Electron Forge resolving path to node module using absolute path rather than using relative path
I'm trying to create an app that include the get-windows npm package, but I cannot distribute my app because Electron Forge is using resolving the package to an absolute path rather than a relative path, so the app fails to find the package.
[2024-06-26 11:11:04.968] [info]  getActiveWindow encountered error{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"spawn /Users/runner/work/<BRANCH_NAME>/node_modules/get-windows/main","path":"/Users/runner/work/<BRANCH_NAME>/node_modules/get-windows/main","spawnargs":["--no-screen-recording-permission"],"cmd":"/Users/runner/work/<BRANCH_NAME>/node_modules/get-windows/main --no-screen-recording-permission","stdout":"","stderr":""}

As you can see, it's trying to run the get-windows package from the runner user (GH actions runner) The following are my configs around get-windows, I am using Electron Forge:
asar: {
  unpack: '**/node_modules/get-windows/**'
},
hooks: {
  packageAfterPrune: async (_forgeConfig, buildPath) => {
    const cmd = process.platform === "win32" ? "yarn.cmd" : "yarn";
    try {
      spawnSync(cmd, ["add", "get-windows", "--force"], {
      cwd: buildPath,
      stdio: "inherit",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("caught exception in packageAfterPrune", err);
  }
},

Also note, I am using the following versions:
Node: 20
Electron: 26.0.0
electron-forge/cli: ^6.0.4
get-windows: ^9.1.1
Please let me know if there's any missing info.
What I've tried:

Removing the asar option, resulting in a runtime error
Removing the packageAfterPrune hook, resulting in the same error


Having the same issue here. Did you ever find a solution?
